# как в mongoose выбрать элементы, например, от 10 до 30

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

как в mongoose выбрать элементы,
например, от 10 до 30.
Вариант с получением массива объектов не канает, так как данных очень много

Comment: skip/limit  в помощь